# Take whole available hight for a TableRow

Tags: android, layout

I use a TableLayout with two TableRows. One row contains three buttons. The other should take all remaining space for its output. How can this be accomplished? Either in XML or with the onMeasure method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with using tables, but I know usually when you're laying out forms, if you want something like that, you lay out the things which are going to be normal size. Then you lay out the thing that is going to take up the remainder of the screen and set it's height property to "fill_parent".  If you'll paste your code in I'd be happy to take a look at it and fix it for you. :-)

-Jared

Answer (score 0):

Although its too late but still i would like to try this. Can u please try this and check whether this helps you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </ListView>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I haven't programmed for Android since several months. But thank you anyway.